# Concatenating different data with the same ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I am required to write a SQL query to migrate the data into an Excel file, I'm able to transfer data from other tables using ORA_EXCEL but I am unable to do the same for this particular part as it requires me to add them into this format. So I planned to create a new table and call it from that new table. I'm currently using Oracle 10g. Below shows an example of the table that I have

STUDENT_BOOK_RECORD (---Table Name---)

```
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|BOOK_ID|CHECKED_BY|DATE_OF_LOAN|HOURS_OF_LOAN|    COMMENTS   |   Student  |
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|   1   |  Mr.Alex |   1/1/17   |      1      |Its a good read|   Bob      |
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|   2   | Miss Li  |   1/2/16   |     0.5     |  Its alright  |   Tom      |
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|   2   | Miss Li  |   1/1/17   |      3      | Its a bad book|   Tim      |
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|   1   |  Mr.Alex |   3/1/15   |      2      |   Its boring  |   Jane     |
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|   1   |  Mr.Alex |   4/1/12   |      5      |   Fun to read |   Sally    |
+-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

Right now I'm trying create a table with the concatenated data based on the similar BOOK_ID and sort the Information in the BOOK_DESCRIPTION by Date.

LIBRARY_BOOK_RECORD (---Table Name---)

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  BOOK_ID  |                BOOK_DESCRIPTION               |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|           | Total Hours of Loan: 8                        |
|           | -----------------------------------------     |
|           | Written by: Mr.Alex                           |
|           | Date of Loan : 4/1/12                         |
|           | Hour(s) of Loan: 5                            |
|           | Comments: Fun to read                         |
|           | Student: Sally                                |
|           | -----------------------------------------     |
|           | Written by: Mr.Alex                           |
|     1     | Date of Loan : 3/1/15                         |
|           | Hour(s) of Loan: 2                            |
|           | Comments: Its boring                          |
|           | Student: Jane                                 |
|           | -----------------------------------------     |
|           | Written by: Mr.Alex                           |
|           | Date of Loan : 1/1/17                         |
|           | Hour(s) of Loan: 1                            |
|           | Comments: Its a good read                     |
|           | Student: Bob                                  |
|           | -----------------------------------------     |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|           | Total Hours of Loan: 3.5                      |
|           | -----------------------------------------     |
|           | Written by: Miss Li                           |
|           | Date of Loan : 1/2/16                         |
|           | Hour(s) of Loan: 0.5                          |
|     2     | Comments: Its alright                         |
|           | Student: Tom                                  |
|           | -----------------------------------------     |
|           | Written by: Miss Li                           |
|           | Date of Loan : 1/1/17                         |
|           | Hour(s) of Loan: 3                            |
|           | Comments: Its a bad book                      |
|           | Student: Tim                                  |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Please help!!! and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your desired output is not traditional output for a SQL query.  You should do the rearranging at the application level.

Comment: `LISTAGG()` might get you halfway there, but as @Gordon said, if you really want this exact format, it should be done in your app code.

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff, thank you for your suggestion but I am required to write an SQL query for this assignment in order to migrate the data into another format.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen, thank you for your help, I will be looking into LISTAGG() and yes I really require this exact format. I have to write a SQL query and migrate the data into an Excel file, I'm able to transfer data from other tables using ORA_EXCEL but I am unable to do the same for this particular part as it requires me to add them into this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work. Of course, there is no way to exactly align the `book_id` in its column (perhaps you can do at least that much in your reporting software). I also followed your lead and used two-digit numbers for the year, although that is a very poor practice, best avoided. Since that is not the topic of your question, I left it alone.

In the query below, first I create a "factored subquery" (the `WITH` clause at the top) for testing purposes. In your work you don't need it; you only need the query that begins below the commented line. Use your actual table and column names.

```
with
     student_book ( book_id, checked_by, date_of_loan, hours_of_loan, comments, student )
     as (
       select 1, 'Mr.Alex', to_date('1/1/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 1  , 'Its a good read', 'Bob'
         from dual union all
       select 2, 'Miss Li', to_date('1/2/16', 'mm/dd/rr'), 0.5, 'Its alright'    , 'Tom'
         from dual union all
       select 2, 'Miss Li', to_date('1/1/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 3  , 'Its a bad book' , 'Tim'
         from dual union all
       select 1, 'Mr.Alex', to_date('3/1/15', 'mm/dd/rr'), 2  , 'Its boring'     , 'Jane'
         from dual union all
       select 1, 'Mr.Alex', to_date('4/1/12', 'mm/dd/rr'), 5  , 'Fun to read'    , 'Sally'
         from dual
     )
--  end of test data; SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select book_id,
       'Total Hours of Loan: ' || to_char(sum(hours_of_loan)) || chr(10) || 
       lpad('-', 30, '-')      || chr(10) ||
       listagg(descr, chr(10)  || lpad('-', 30, '-') || chr(10))
               within group (order by date_of_loan)  as book_description
from   (
         select book_id, date_of_loan, hours_of_loan,
                'Written by: '      || checked_by                          || chr(10) ||
                'Date of Loan : '   || to_char(date_of_loan, 'mm/dd/yy')   || chr(10) ||
                'Hour(s) of Loan: ' || to_char(hours_of_loan)              || chr(10) ||
                'Comments: '        || comments                            || chr(10) ||
                'Student: '         || student      as descr
         from   student_book
       )
group by book_id
order by book_id
;
```

**Output**:

```
BOOK_ID BOOK_DESCRIPTION
------- --------------------------------
      1 Total Hours of Loan: 8
        ------------------------------
        Written by: Mr.Alex
        Date of Loan : 04/01/12
        Hour(s) of Loan: 5
        Comments: Fun to read
        Student: Sally
        ------------------------------
        Written by: Mr.Alex
        Date of Loan : 03/01/15
        Hour(s) of Loan: 2
        Comments: Its boring
        Student: Jane
        ------------------------------
        Written by: Mr.Alex
        Date of Loan : 01/01/17
        Hour(s) of Loan: 1
        Comments: Its a good read
        Student: Bob

      2 Total Hours of Loan: 3.5
        ------------------------------
        Written by: Miss Li
        Date of Loan : 01/02/16
        Hour(s) of Loan: .5
        Comments: Its alright
        Student: Tom
        ------------------------------
        Written by: Miss Li
        Date of Loan : 01/01/17
        Hour(s) of Loan: 3
        Comments: Its a bad book
        Student: Tim
```

**Edit**: For Oracle versions before 11, `listagg()` will not work. `xmlagg()` existed earlier (I believe). The following modification should work. (It produces an extra "line of dashes" at the bottom of each book description, which can be removed if needed - I didn't bother with that).

REPLACE

```
   listagg(descr, chr(10)  || lpad('-', 30, '-') || chr(10))
           within group (order by date_of_loan)  as book_description
```

WITH

```
xmlagg(xmlelement(x, descr, chr(10) || lpad('-', 30, '-') || chr(10)).extract('//text()')
                         order by date_of_loan)  as book_description
```

Comment: Hey @mathguy Thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply =D I never thought of writing the query in that way but I couldn't use the "LISTAGG" as the Version of my Oracle is 10g and the LISTAGG can only be used in Oracle 12c, Oracle 11g Release 2, sorry for not mentioning it earlier. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: @Laran -  I'll add something to the Answer; I believe `xmlagg` is available in Oracle 10.